# Redis Session State Provider not deleting keys on Session Abandon

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am storing the Session State in an Azure Redis Cache, using this [procedure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/).

The NuGet [RedisSessionStateProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider) saves you Session State in Redis and you can manage it as it was clasiccal inProc Session.

When the user login i make something like this:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
Session.Add("key", "value");
```

The session value is created an available all time in the application.
If you look at your REDIS cache you will see this two keys `snurztvlyl2jk5wnzstjikln_Internal` `snurztvlyl2jk5wnzstjikln_Data` where  `snurztvlyl2jk5wnzstjikln` is the SessionID.

When I signout:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
Session.Abandon();
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The user SignOut but if I look at the redis cache the values persist. They are not deleted and only are deleted after the session time out. I also tried `Session.Clear()` and the keys in the Redis cache still persist.

Why the keys are not deleted or what am I doing wrong?

**Update** I create a public repo reproducing this issue
https://github.com/ricardopolo/RedisIssue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I contacted the creators of the NuGet RedisSessionStateProvider and they explain me its a expected behavior.

They said:

> Now you perform Logout which calls “Session.Abandon()”. This operation
>   actually removes session from Redis but then RedirectToAction("Index",
>   "Home") causes call to “GetItemExclusive” (a method inside session
>   state provider) which tries to find session but didn’t find so it in
>   turn calls “CreateUninitializedItem” which creates empty session with
>   SessionStateActions set to InitializeItem (or 1). So at this point if
>   you do HGETALL on this session you will see key “SessionStateActions”
>   and not “Key”. Because this is newly created empty session and not
>   the old one.
>
> This is how ASP.NET MVC is designed. You should see same behavior with
>   all other providers as well. Check
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587(v=vs.140).aspx) for
>   more details about session state methods and their meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I was kind of able to reproduce it. After Session.Abandon() everything is removed from cache but then ResetItemTimeout gets called and it updates internal key (*_Internal). So user sees Internal key in Redis. But I don't see *_Data available after Session.Abandon() which contains actual session data.

I have resolved this bug related to *_Internal and released a new nuget package. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/1.3.0)

If you still see the issue with this new version let us know.

Comment: Thanks, using this latest Nuget version the issue persist. I updated the question a github repo reproducing the issue.